# How to display components using their selector in Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript

Right now I'm playing around with Angular 17 (Angular CLI: 17.0.0).

The directory is structured as follows:

```
/src
    /app
        /x
            x.component.css
            x.component.html
            x.component.spec.ts
            x.component.ts
        app.component.css
        app.component.html
        app.component.spec.ts
        app.component.ts
        app.config.ts
        app.routes.ts
    /assets
    favicon.ico
    index.html
    main.ts
    styles.css
```

I want to include the content of my component `x` by adding `<app-x></app-x>` to `app.component.html` and importing `x` in `app.component.ts`. However the content of that component is not displayed in the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if `app.component.ts` is a Standalone component you can simply import the `x.component` in its decorator and use `<app-x></app-x>` in the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the class of your component defined in x.component.ts

```
export class XComponent {

}
```

Then on your app.component.ts you add in the imports array

```
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, XComponent],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I did. Turns out I've had an issue somewhere else that prevented the contents of XComponent to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

inside @component in  x.component.ts standalone should be declared to true
standalone: true